# Why doesn't the entity refer to the entity that created it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, rest

I have the entity "Teacher", which can create courses. The problem is that when creating a course, for some reason it does not remember the teacher who created it. The teacher himself does not have this course either. The update method doesn't help the teacher.

```
public async Task<CourseResponse> AddCourse(CourseAddRequest courseAddRequest, Guid teacherId)
       {
            var teacher = await _teacherRepository.GetTeacher(teacherId);

            if (teacher == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("User doesn't exist");
            }
            var course = _mapper.Map<Course>(courseAddRequest);
            course.Teacher = teacher;
            course.TeacherId = teacher.Id;
            var addedCourse = await _courseRepository.AddCourse(course);
            teacher.Courses.Add(addedCourse);
            teacher = await _teacherRepository.UpdateTeacher(teacher);
            return _mapper.Map<CourseResponse>(addedCourse);
        }
```

Teacher:

```
public class Teacher : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public List<Course> Courses { get; set; } = new List<Course>();
    }
```

Course:

```
public class Course : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Header { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Guid TeacherId { get; set; }
        public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }

        public List<Student> StudentsOnCourse { get; set; } = new List<Student>();
    }
```

I`m trying to organize relationships one too many, but it doesn't help.

```
class CourseEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Course>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Course> builder)
        {

            builder.HasOne(c => c.Teacher)
                .WithMany(t => t.Courses)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.TeacherId);            
            
        }
    }

public class UniDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public UniDbContext(DbContextOptions<UniDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(CourseEntityTypeConfiguration).Assembly);


        }
    }
```

In Startup:

```
services.AddDbContext<UniDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                    sqlOpt => sqlOpt.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(UniDbContext).Assembly.FullName)
            ));
```

I have a git repository where the whole project is located: https://github.com/ChuvashPeople/UniversityProject

Thx for the help.

Comment: "The problem is that when creating a course, for some reason it does not remember the teacher who created it.", have you checked the database? What happens when it's created? Is the teacher ID inside the database and associated with the course?

Comment: The answer is in your Database. I would guess that because the result from GetTeacher() is not tracked (not by the CourseRepo anyway) you get a new Teacher whn you save the Course. But debug your tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at your source and the culprit is almost certainly your "Update" methods:

```
public async Task<Teacher> UpdateTeacher(Teacher teacher)
{
    var oldTeacher = await _uniDbContext.Teachers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == teacher.Id);
    _uniDbContext.Teachers.Remove(oldTeacher);
    await _uniDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    await _uniDbContext.Teachers.AddAsync(teacher);
    await _uniDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    return teacher;
}
```

This is a completely wrong way to go about an update as you are going to be tripping up on what references are being passed around.

My suggestion would be to start a LOT simpler. Do away with the repository pattern until you have a legitimate need for it. If you have dependency injection set up, for a start just reference the DbContext within your controller. Once you understand how that works and want to introduce a repository to enable unit testing, then abstract from there. The next suggestion would be to use the synchronous methods until there is an explicit benefit for using an `async` variant. `async` doesn't make code faster, it actually makes it slower. What it can do is make a web server more responsive when you need to execute something that can take a while, or are doing an operation which is going to get called a heck of a lot. Updating a record by ID doesn't fit either of these scenarios. (Running complex searches / reports is an example where async can help avoid your web server from bogging down)

```
public CourseResponse AddCourse(CourseAddRequest courseAddRequest, Guid teacherId)
{
    var teacher = _uniDbContext.Teachers
        .Include(t => t.Courses)
        .SingleOrDefault(t => t.Id == teacherId);

    if (teacher == null)
        throw new Exception("User doesn't exist");

    var course = _mapper.Map<Course>(courseAddRequest);
    teacher.Courses.Add(course);
    _uniDbContext.SaveChanges();
    return _mapper.Map<CourseResponse>(course);
}
```

Here when you go to load a Teacher, include (eager load) the Courses collection, as you may also want to do a check that the added course already isn't associated with the Teacher. (not shown) From there you just need to add the Course to the loaded teacher entity and save the changes. EF will take care of associating the course back to the teacher and setting the FKs.

I do not recommend using a Repository pattern overtop of the EF DbContext other than to make unit testing more accessible, giving you a simpler interface to mock than trying to mock a DbContext & DbSets. Having a repository that returns materialized entities or sets of entities (`List<Teacher>` etc) is extremely inefficient and doesn't allow for details like eager loading related entities, (courses, etc.) filtering, pagination, or projecting data down into just what the views actually need. When you do look at unit testing around the repository I would recommend reading up on the `IQueryable` support within EF so that repositories can serve as a thin, substitutable interface for unit testing while still accommodating all of the capabilities that EF can provide.

** Update **

A couple details from looking at the code:

1. By default EF will expect PKs that follow default naming convention ("Id" or "TeacherId" etc.) to be identity columns where SQL Server would be responsible for populating the PKs. If you want to set Ids in code, you should mark the PK column as `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None`. Otherwise I would remove any code setting a default Id value. This may be tripping up FK references.
2. When configuring relationships, only configure them from one side or the other, not both. If you configure a `.HasMany().WithOne()` on the Teacher, then remove the `.HasOne().WithMany()` on the course.  Reference properties should ideally be marked as virtual to ensure that EF can generate proxies for change tracking.

I'm not sure if either of these would relate to that error, but it may be. I know EF can do some odd things when reference configuration are doubled up.

Comment: I'm new in asp.net. Maybe I didn't understand something? I tried to run the code above, but it resulted in an error: "Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded."

Comment: I've added a couple of additional things to check based on another look at the code.